# Как реализовать переход между activity сохраняя сокет-соединение?

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер

Пробую свои силы в клиент-серверах и наткнулся на такую проблему, если я хочу чтобы на стороне клиента после подключения к серверу сменился `Activity`, но соединение не потерялось, то как это реализовать понять не могу. 
Подключение клиента реализовывал в `AsyncTask`, который получается привязан к одному `Activity`.

Для наглядного понимания вот пример:

Допустим все клиенты сначала собираются в "комнате", а после того как все подключились дается команда перейти на другое `Activity` с вопросами. Что-то типо онлайн викторины где все стартуют одновременно.

Comment: делайте все в сервисе. Активити не нужно знать о том, что есть сокет.

Comment: @KoVadim, Я не до конца разобрался с сервисами, но из того, что я про них знаю - они вроде работают без участи UI, но мне надо, что бы когда каждый клиент что-то нажимает, то это должно отображаться экранах других клиентов. Такое возможно?

Comment: а почему нет? как раз для Вашего случая и созданы сервисы. Сервис занимается сетевой работой, а активити общаются с сервисом.

Comment: @KoVadim, Спасибо большое) Пойду разбираться с сервисами. Почему то сложилось плотное ощущение, что сервисы это просто фоновая работа приложения, в основном для уведомлений)

PS а если сервер блютус, то там все тоже самое?

Comment: Не обязательно сервис. Можно обычный синглетон, вне активности

Answer (score 3):

есть один вариант. Запускать этот AsyncTask только один раз, и тогда можно будет обращаться к нему из любого `Activity`.

```java
public class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

   private static DownloadWebPageTask downloadWebPageTask;
   private Socket socket; // Это для соединения с сервером

   private DownloadWebPageTask(){ }

   public static synchronized DownloadWebPageTask getInstance( ) {
      if (downloadWebPageTask == null)
          downloadWebPageTask = new DownloadWebPageTask ();
      return downloadWebPageTask;
   }

   //...
}
```

использовать так (из любого `Activity`)

```
   DownloadWebPageTask downloadWebPageTask = DownloadWebPageTask.getInstance();
   downloadWebPageTask.execute(a, b, c);
```

Comment: Вот только из вашего решение не понятно где будет храниться ссылка на открытое соединение.

Comment: Соединение будет внутри этого `AsyncTask`. В вопросе нету как они сделали это делали. из этого я не указывал

Comment: Синглетон, но не самый удачный пример

Comment: Согласен, можно были и сам `AsyncTask` передать другому `Activity`. Но этот метод самый быстрый для перехода. Позже конечно лучше сделать  `Service`

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev разве не получается тогда, что соединение будет утеряно во время перехода и восстановлено после?

P.S. почему это не самый удачный пример?

Comment: пока объект `AsyncTask` существует, соединение не потеряется. Если оно удалится, при новом вызове соединение заново создатся.